# Docker ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, docker

I'm trying to make a web app using django and in views.py file I added import boto3 .

it worked perfectly when i tried it without docker but now i get this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'`

so here is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install boto3 -t .
COPY . /app/
ADD . /app
ENV PYTHONPATH /app
CMD [ "python", "/app/greet/views.py" ]
```

and this is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes: 
      - .:/app
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
```

Edit:

I've also tried this but it doesn't work either, with boto3 in `requirements.txt` :

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app/
```

Comment: How does the `requirements.txt` file looks like?

Comment: here it is : ```Django==3.2
boto3==1.16.63```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the `volumes` section of your `docker-compose.yml`. In your `Dockerfile`, you go to lots of effort to set up `/app`, including installing `boto3` into that directory...

...and then you go and just mount your local directory on top of it,
effectively hiding everything contained in `/app` in the container
image.

The solution is either:

- Do not mount anything on top of `/app`. Get rid of the `volumes`
  section of your configuration and just rebuild the image when you need
  to refresh the code. Or...
- Rather than installing `boto3` into `/app`, just include it in
  `requirements.txt` and install it along with other dependencies. Now mounting something on `/app` won't hide `boto3`.

Comment: In a Python image without a virtual environment, I'd expect packages to be installed into somewhere like `/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages`, which wouldn't have this specific problem?  (As distinct from a Node application, where `/app/node_modules` gets hidden by the bind mount.)

Comment: ...the [`pip install -t .`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-t) option makes this be a concern again.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I've already added boto3 in requirements.txt and it doesn't work. and when i removed `volumes` section i get this error : `python: can't open file '/app/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: I am very confident that I have correctly identified both the problem and the solution. If you'd like to to update your question to include a link to your complete project, I would be happy to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar issue using `RUN pip install --user ...` in the Dockerfile, which will install modules to `/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` instead of `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` by default.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for some reason python is installing boto3 in `/usr/lib/python3.x/site-packages` instead of `/usr/local/lib/python3.x/site-packages` which is the default .

`/usr/lib/python3.x/site-packages` this folder isnt included in PYTHONPATH in docker container, so either do that manually, or shift the module to the other folder